# How do I create a Handlebars template to be compiled at runtime in an Assemble build?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js, assemble

I'm doing a site which I'm building with Assemble. Assemble basically renders a static version of a site using Handlebars templates and injects data from json files. That's working for most of my project.

However, there is an area of my site where I want to load data at runtime and render it into a template using Handlebars.js. The normal way to do that is to put it into a script tag...

```
<script id="list-item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li>Item {{id}}</li>
</script>
```

But when I do that, Assemble renders the content inside that template into

```
<script id="list-item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li>Item </li>
</script>
```

Note, {{id}} is removed (compiled to ''). Is there a way I can force Assemble to NOT compile some hbs content? Is there some other method I should use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can escaped handlebars templates using `\` before the handlebars tag...

```
<li> item \{{id}}</li>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to do this for an entire partial at once?

Comment: You should look at a way to pre-process the client side templates and load them into your app separately instead of inlining them inside script tags. This way you don't need to escape the client side templates and can still build out your server side templates with assemble. There are different ways of doing this depending on the rest of your build process.